# Javascript variable - AJAX- send to server without waitting for answer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My click counter do not send variable to server.

I tried to find some example how to create, but whatever i tried, there is no attempt to send data to server.It looks like AJAX should be best option, but i do something wrong.  i tried also window.location.href  javascript, but this redirect me to other page and i want continue in current srcipt.

court1.js:

```
var button = document.getElementById("clickme"),
  count = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  button.innerHTML = "result: " + count;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'count.php',
    data:+count,
});
};
```

index.html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: lightblue; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    -90deg,
    lightblue,
    black
  ); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    -90deg,
    lightblue,
    black
  ); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    -90deg,
    lightblue,
    black
  ); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, lightblue, black); /* Standard syntax */
}

.main {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #202020;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  color: lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <h3>court 1</h3>
    <button id="clickme">click here</button>


  </div>
<script src="court1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

counter is working perfectly..  after refresh count from 0. 
But i dont see any attempt to send variable to server. Debugging mode in chrome doesn't show any activity.

I need after every touch (click) send new value from variable $count to server.  Counter have to continue in work without any disturbing. We are talking about few clicks per seccond.
I would like to send new value to php script or also i am open to send new value by UDP packet to server and gather data on server through syslog-ng.

Priority is minimal load of resources on client side. 
thank you for your help

Comment: You have written +count. It won’t increment the value. You should have ++count (unary operator). Also see in chrome - Dev tools - network tab if there is ajax/xhr request sent or not.

Comment: The data also has to be valid payload, I would recommend making JS object (aka json) and send it in ajax call. Or if it’s just a single numeric value, you can make data as empty and pass this number in url itself as query/request param to the server.

Comment: Assign the result of the call to `$.ajax()` to variable `request`. Then add statements to call functions `request.done` and `request.fail` passing to each functions to be called on successful and failure completions respectively. In that way you might better understand what is happening.

Comment: @SagarAgrawal _"JS object (aka json)"_ - No, a "JS object" is absolutely not [JSON](http://json.org)!

Comment: @SagarAgrawal   even it should not increment,, counter is working fine..   Anyway i am not able to send any value..  I checked chrome network dev tools,, and i dont see any activity .. no request to my php script or whereever..

Comment: @Ronald Aaronson:    sorry ,,i am beginner in javascript ...  i dont need any result...  if i can send simple udp with integer as data it is enought for me..  any response will load my client device, so the best option should be send by ajax with no answer from server.

Comment: I think the server has to send *some* response to a `post` request. Ajax is asynchronous so you do not have to wait for the response nor process the response. I was making the suggestion so you can see what errors may have occurred.

Comment: I think I know your problem: The `data` param should be something like `data: {"count" : count`}. In other words, you should be passing an object that looks like a dictionary of name/value pairs.

Comment: @Ronald Aaronson   this is not problem.   i tried your fix,, but there is no activity from client to server. So there is some bigger issue that ajax is not activated.

this script is loaded from server... so server sent this script and html to client..  but script inside is not able to send data to server.

Comment: See answer by @goose. If you are missing jQuery library, that will surely be a **BIG, BIG** problem. But you will need my change, too. Look at the console tab for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is that there is no loaded jquery in HTML code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

this is main reason, why ajax is not activated.